# How to generate a faceted bar plot with reverse Y-axis and specified ylim in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need help on how to generate a reversed stacked bar plot with specific ylim. I have used the code below for this purpose but the plot is generated in reverse order as expected but the ylim option did not work i.e, the y-axis labels were auto generated.

This is the data:

```r
df <- structure(list(z = c("up", "up", "up", "up", "up", "up", "down", 
"down", "down", "down", "down", "down"), x = c("C", "C", "G", "G", "H", "H",
 "C", "C", "G", "G", "H", "H"), w = c("more", "less", "more", "less", "more", 
"less", "more", "less", "more", "less", "more", "less"), y = c(5, 6, 4, 4, 
50, 42, 50, 16, 24, 8, 83, 99)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
 row.names = c(NA, -12L)
```

My code is

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill=w))+geom_bar(stat='identity')+ facet_wrap(~z, scales="free_y", ncol = 1) +xlab('a')+ylab('b')+theme(panel.background = element_blank(),axis.text = element_text(size = 8, color = 'black'), text = element_text(size = 8),plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+ggtitle('T')+ ylim(0,500)+scale_y_continuous(trans="reverse")
```

However, using the same code without reversing the plot generates a stacked plot in an upright position and with ylim as specified.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill=w))+geom_bar(stat='identity')+ facet_wrap(~z, scales="free_y", ncol = 1) +xlab('a')+ylab('b')+theme(panel.background = element_blank(),axis.text = element_text(size = 8, color = 'black'), text = element_text(size = 8),plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+ggtitle('T')+ ylim(0,500)
 "scale_y_continuous(trans="reverse")",
```

I need help on how to successfully generate this plot.
Thanks

Comment: Hi Allan. Here is my data: 
        structure(list(z = c("up", "up", "up", "up", "up", "up", "down", "down", "down", "down", "down", "down"), x = c("C", "C", "G", "G", "H", "H", "C", "C", "G", "G", "H", "H"), w = c("more", "less", "more", "less", "more", "less", "more", "less", "more", "less", "more", "less"), y = c(5, 6, 4, 4, 50, 42, 50, 16, 24, 8, 83, 99)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -12L)).                                                                                          I am new to stackflow and not sure if this data format is clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `scale_y_reverse` instead of `scale_y_continuous` with `trans = "reverse"`. You can specify the limits using the `limits` argument rather than an extra call to `ylim`, and you need to specify the numbers from highest to lowest.

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = w)) +
  geom_col() + 
  facet_wrap(~z, scales = "free_y", ncol = 1) +
  labs(x = 'a', y = "b", title = "T") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 8, color = 'black'), 
        text = element_text(size = 8),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
   scale_y_reverse(limits = c(500, 0))
```

[image]